# Issue with inserting data PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I'm trying to insert data which a user has filled out (register form) I am having issue, with it not inserting the data, and at the same time giving me NO error or reason why, I have checked my logs and everything, nothing seems to be wrong. But my query isn't executed.

```
  /* IN THIS FUNCTION WE REGISTER THE USER, WE CREATE A SALT, INSERT THAT SALT KEY INTO SALTS TABLE, THEN GET THE ID AND USE THAT ID IN PASSYSTEM TABLE WHERE WE STORE THE PASSWORD AND THE SALT ID THE MEMBER DATA IS STORED IN MEMBERS TABLE*/
    $data = $_POST;
    print_r($data);
    $salt = $this->gen_salt();
    $password =  hash('sha512', $salt.$data['password'].$salt, FALSE);
    print $password;
      $membersql = "INSERT INTO member (`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`gender`) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :gender)";
      $memberquery = $db->prepare($membersql);
      $memberquery->bindParam(':firstname', $data['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $memberquery->bindParam(':lastname', $data['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $memberquery->bindParam(':email', $data['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $memberquery->bindParam(':gender', $data['gender'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $memberquery->execute();
```

Comment: Do you have a foreign key in your database? or any unique keys preventing you from inserting? what happens if you execute your query directly in your database using software?

Comment: According to my ERD the member table has no FK

Comment: Can you execute your query if you use software like phpmyadmin or heidisql to execute it?

Comment: The error MySQL Workbench threw out. Was Error code 1054, unknown column Russell in field list

Comment: Could you paste in the query you executed?

Comment: including the params like :firstname

Comment: The query above. INSERT INTO member ('firstname',  'lastname', 'email', 'gender') VALUES ('Russell', 'Harrower', 'email@test.com', 'm');

Comment: firstname lastname email gender should be quoted with these `` try if this works.

Comment: That worked in workbench but not when I " in PHP

Comment: What does $data['firstname'] return? I assume Russell? And do you have the :firstname quoted in your query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69801/discussion-between-stijn-bernards-and-russellharrower).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something is wrong with bindparam.

Try it like this:

```
$membersql = "INSERT INTO member (firstname,lastname,email,gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$memberquery->execute(array($data['firstname'], $data['lastname'], $data['email'], $data['gender']));
```

This should work correctly.